# TextSecureServer-7.5.1 not run

Tags: java, maven, signals

Steps to install and compile. :

```
git clone https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Server.git

cd Signal-Server

mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 17.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.11.0-1022-aws", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

~/Signal-Server$ java -version
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)

mvn clean install -DskipTests   

java -jar service/target/TextSecureServer-7.5.1-dirty-SNAPSHOT.jar server config/sample.yml
```

I get this error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in service/target/TextSecureServer-7.5.1-dirty-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? If more data is needed, I will provide.

Comment: mvn clean install -DskipTests -Pexclude-abusive-message-filter